# Redux Persiste - Size Limit

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-persist

i have a react/redux app and i'm using redux-persist to store state values.
I have a big amount of data and i want to know the size limit of redux-persist, i know that redux can store an illimited data but with redux persiste i have no idea.
Any help please ?
This is what i found on the internet :

```
A Redux store doesn't have a limit on the amount of data stored, so you can pretty much use it to store almost anything, including bulky JSON data, data in table form, etc.
```

Thank you

Comment: Hey, @Tania12 did you get anything on it? from my redux-persist data get removed every time I close the app, on android 12 but it's fine on android 11 and iOS, any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `localStorage`, you probably want to check [What is the max size of localStorage values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values)

A quick test shows me a limit of 5 mb per domain (latest Chrome and Safari on macOS). But you probably shouldn't rely on that. I'd use something like 2.4 mb as a reasonable limit.